# Show that the function $f: N \to N$ given by ..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Show that the function $f:N \to N$ given by 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x+1 & \text{If $x$ is odd} \\ x-1 & \text{If $x$ is even} \end{cases} $$ is bijective.

My Attempt:

Case$1$. Suppose $x_1$ is odd and $x_2$ is even.
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
$$x_1 + 1= x_2 -1$$
$$x_2 - x_1=2$$
This is impossible. So, our assumption is invalid.

Case$2$. Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are even.
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
$$x_1 - 1= x_2 -1$$
$$x_1=x_2$$

Case$3$. Supppse $x_1$ and $x_2$ are odd
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
$$x_1+1=x_2+1$$
$$x_1=x_2$$.

Comment: Hint: Compute $f(f(x))$

Comment: I think $\mathbb{N}$ is usually taken to be $\{0,1,...\}$ these days, rather than $\{1,2,...\}$. Where does $0$ go?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, what does it help for?

Comment: @MartinRattigan, what is $N$?

Comment: You have successfully shown that $f$ is injective, or one-to-one. Now you need to show that it is surjective / onto, and you're done.

Comment: @Arthur, why does $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ have to be done? How $x_1=x_2$ shows the function is injective? How to show that it is injective?

Comment: You ask what $N$ is, but its used used in your question, so you are the one who should answer that. My comment assumed that $N$ was meant to be taken as $\mathbb{N}$. Perhaps its meant to be taken as $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By definition, $f$ is **injective** when

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)\to x_1=x_2$$

So, taking $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ we have the possibilities:

$1)$ If $x_1,x_2$ are odd then, $x_1+1=x_2+1\to x_1=x_2$

$2)$ If $x_1,x_2$ are even then, $x_1-1=x_2-1\to x_1=x_2$

$3)$ If $x_1$ is odd and $x_2$ is even then $x_1+1=x_2-1\to x_1-x_2=-2$, what is impossible.

Then just the case $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be true and we get that $f$ is injective.

- Now we have to prove that $f$ is surjective. By definition, $f$ is **surjective** if $\text{Image}(f)=\Bbb N$.

Let's then take some $y_0\in \Bbb N$ and we must to prove that there is some $x_0$ in the domain, which is $\Bbb N$ such that $f(x_0)=y_0$.

$1)$ If $y_0$ is odd then take $x_0=y_0+1$, which will be even, and then we will get $f(x_0)=x_0-1=y_0+1-1=y_0$;

$2)$ If $y_0$ is even then take $x_0=y_0-1$, which will be odd, and then we will get $f(x_0)=x_0+1=y_0-1+1=y_0$;

So $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a function $g: X \to Y$ is bijective if and only if it is injective and surjective, if and only if for every $y \in Y$ there is **exactly one** $x \in X$ such that $g(x) = y$. Let $y \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $y$ is either odd or even. If $y$ is odd, then $y+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ and is even; note that $x := (y+1)$ implies $f(x) = (y+1)-1 = y$. If there is some $x' \neq x$ such that $x' \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x') = f(x) = y$, then $x'$ even implies $x' - 1 = y$ and $x'$ odd implies $x'+1$ is even; both leads to a contradiction. Now you can use the same argument to argue for the case where $y$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

A bijection is an *injection* and a *surjection*. You have shown that this is an *injection* (although, depending on the level of your course, it might help to add an extra word about why your first case is "impossible"). All that remains now is to show that the function is also a *surjection*, i.e., that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(k) = n$.